# Does the Watson iOS SDK allow for access to the customization STT model

Tags: ibm-watson

The WatsonSpeech STT api (recognizeMicrophone method) takes an JSON object with key "customization_id" which allows the STT to use custom terms the user might say.

I don't see this ability in the Watson iOS SDK, I mean there is no customization_id parameter in the API.  Is there some other way to use the customized STT with the Watson iOS SDK?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added support for using a custom Speech to Text model with this [commit](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/commit/0de2ddec56fd5d3a4d3a1477800176a0eae8b351) last week. We'll be publishing a release soon to make those changes more easily accessible through Carthage.

Comment: The release you speak of. That will be a 0.8+ release (meaning will be available for Swift 2.3)?  Thanks.

Comment: Yup. We will be publishing a release for both Swift 2.2 (v0.7.x) and Swift 2.3 (v0.8.x). The changes will also be merged into the Swift 3.0 branch, which will be published at a later date.

Comment: We released [v0.7.2 for Swift 2.2](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.7.2) and [v0.8.1 for Swift 2.3](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/releases/tag/v0.8.1) with support for specifying a Speech to Text customization id.

Comment: We started using the customized STT today and then reverted back. We were seeing a lot of Websocket timeouts.  Not sure if it is the Watson iOS SDK code or our backend services.  But we do have a web app that uses customized STT and it doesn't have this problem.